Why do dock stations have a rather low supported disk capacity?
I see on https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00LS5NFQ2?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details&th=1 (see screenshot below) that many dock stations have a rather low supported disk capacity. Where do these 8TB and  20TB limits come from? Why can't dock station support very large disks, or even have a limit on the supported disk capacity?


In reply to comments mentioning Amazon's frequent product description inaccuracies (which I've indeed also witnessed many times), the limits are confirmed on the manufacturer's official site, e.g. https://sabrent.com/products/ec-dffn:


20TB is more or less the current maximum of any drive on the market. It likely supports larger than 20TB but likely not specifically validated. The manufacturer of every single one of those devices also makes very cheap devices.

@Ramhound Why does it need validation? And why don't they update their old 8TB limit?

VTC: not opinion-based, I'm looking for objective answers (e.g., Ramhound's comment  is  a valid answer).

What? 8TB would be the expected maximum size of a 2.5” drive due to the size. It’s also possible that comparison isn’t accurate. Amazon is notorious for having bad information on product pages since they definitely never validate it themselves.

@Ramhound good point I didn't see the 2.5. Why does it need  validation?

Most likely it is marketing speak. Where it says "supported" read "we tested this and therefore our technical support people will deign to speak to you if you have a problem". It needs validation because companies have to be able to prove that they are not lying when they tell you what size of drives they claim to work with. They can't claim to know that they 100% support drives that they have never bothered to test it with. If they say they've tested it with 8TB drives and you say it doesn't work with a 20TB one (it most likely will) then they can just tell you to get lost.

@FranckDernoncourt - It doesn’t need validation but similar to motherboard manufacturers they are not going to guarantee compatibility with something they didn’t test themselves. It could also be SATA to USB chipset compatibility issues, but most likely, it’s as simple as 20TB and 8TB are the largest drives that were actually tested.

@Mokubai thanks, why does the size matter for the compatibility?

Reread my earlier comment.

TS? What's that mean?

@JoepvanSteen why do you say I am pushing it? Just trying to learn.

@JoepvanSteen I've asked over 6k questions on SE, just a few ones are on specific values, and I don't even recall asking another question on why some manufacturer settles for specific values (maybe I forgot, but likely just 2 or 3 such questions).

@JoepvanSteen "they do not seem related to related protocols and specifications." is a valid answer. "We simply don't know where these limitations come from or why a manufacturer lists them": manufacturers' employees also use Internet. They may answer here, or they may have mention it publicly.


Where do these 8TB and 20TB limits come from?

From the data sheet of the manufacturer.

Why can't dock station support very large disks, or even have a limit on the supported disk capacity?

Because that's what the Product Manager felt comfortable writing in the data sheet.

Thanks. "that's what the Product Manager felt comfortable writing in the data sheet." Why did they feel comfortable with that number?

@JoepvanSteen there could be a technical reason behind that choice.

Right now, without widespread use of things like HAMR, and multi actuator drives, 20TB is about a safe bet for the sort of drives you'd put into such a dock. I suspect 8tb's about as large as you can get a 2.5 inch drive, and its likely to be a thicker Z height than normal unless they are SSDs.
While Helium filled drives, and SSDs are likely to just work, a more exotic drive might not. A >30tb drive might use HAMR, MAMR, or multi actuators, and things that might have not been tested when the dock was designed and tested.
It's also a bit of a CYA - I checked the data sheet of one of the two docks I have (which will do 20tb drives) and there's no maximum capacity listed. Its entirely possible that a larger drive will work, or a smaller, exotic dual actuator drive seen as 2 HDDs would not. I couldn't check the datasheet for the other one because it doesn't exist (It's listed as a  2109:0561 VIA Labs, Inc. UnionSine). In theory the second one goes up to 6tb each, but I don't have any free, bigger drives to test if it'll work.
I'd guess that those are the biggest drives they've tested/validated, and it dosen't make sense to keep updating them.
That way if someone bought a drive they didn't test cause it didn't exist when the drive was designed, and it didn't work - well, it's not supported.
